# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got this fatal Exception when running an Android app and pushing the BtnSave button. The btnDelete is working perfectly. I am a beginner and looking for a solution in code. This the complete errorcode. Thx in advance.

```
10-21 06:54:25.777 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe239d0
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.blackactivity, PID: 3690
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.blackactivity.EditProductActivity$SaveProductDetails.doInBackground(EditProductActivity.java:244)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.blackactivity.EditProductActivity$SaveProductDetails.doInBackground(EditProductActivity.java:212)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
10-21 06:54:32.115 3690-3934/com.example.blackactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
10-21 06:54:32.238 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-21 06:54:32.238 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79d140, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-21 06:54:33.090 3690-3690/com.example.blackactivity I/Choreographer: Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-21 06:54:33.516 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-21 06:54:33.516 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa41a7a40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-21 06:54:34.045 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe23a40
10-21 06:54:34.204 3690-3712/com.example.blackactivity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabe23260
```

And this is the code that i am running:

```
package com.example.blackactivity;

/**
 * Created by mtjict on 19-10-2015.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://192.168.178.14/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.168.178.14/android_connect/update_product.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://192.168.178.14/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product

                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {               ///ZIT HIER HET PROBLEEM?????
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
                        System.out.print(pid);
                        //??? Missing parameters

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request


                        // check your log for json response
                         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);  ///??????????????????????????????????

                       // JSONObject json =jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.178.14/android_connect/get_product_details.php","GET",{"pid":"1"});

                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        );

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
           // String name =  txtName.getText().toString();
           // String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
           // String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
      //      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
       //     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        //    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            String name = args[0];
            String price = args[1];
            String description = args[2];

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have three arguments before you access the array:

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
           // String name =  txtName.getText().toString();
           // String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
           // String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
      //      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
       //     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        //    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            String name = null;
            String price = null;
            String description = null;
            if (args.length>0) {
                 name=args[0]
            }
            if (args.length>1) {
                 price=args[1]
            }

            if (args.length>2) {
                 description =args[0]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in `btnSave.setOnClickListener`

```
new SaveProductDetails().execute();
```

with

```
new SaveProductDetails().execute(name, price, description);
```

for more information go through [**this**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) link.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thx